# When switching from non-inferiority to superiority - is the adjustment for significance needed (confusion)?

Tags: hypothesis-testing, statistical-significance, equivalence, non-inferiority

On this blog: http://onbiostatistics.blogspot.com/2012/06/switching-from-non-inferiority-to.html
which also cites the opinion of FDA and EMA we can read, that no adjustment is necessary.

Could anyone tell me, how it's possible and in the 2 cases:

- non-inferiority claimed, no superiority
- non-inferiority claimed, superiority claimed

(other 2 options can be skipped, as the superiority makes no sense to test, when non-inferiority isn't reached).

It seems, that the justification is that if the lower bound of the confidence interval > 0, then it automatically claims both non-INF and SUP.

I assume it means, that just looking at the CI, I immediately know what happens, no need to test twice.

Is that the case?